# how to play caf file in iphone device?

Tags: iphone

i have used following code to play caf sound.but it works in simulator ,not in device...anyone can give solution?

```
 NSString *pathe=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Watermovement3" ofType:@"caf"];
CFURLRef url =(CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathe];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(url,&okk);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(okk);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the capitalization of your filename: is it possible it's "watermovement3" or "WaterMovement3"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the codecs of the caf file. The simulator supports more codecs than the device!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
AVAudioPlayer * avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recordedFileNameURL error:&error];

[avPlayer prepareToPlay];

[avPlayer play];
```